# What if we omit constructor in JS

Tags: javascript

I am new in JS and was learning classes and constructor that is put inside class but I wonder what happens behind the scenes if we omit constructor inside class. For example,

```
class UI{

this.box = document.querySelector(".box");
this.footer = document.querySelector(".footer");

render(){
.......
}

}
```

Is the above code equivalent to

```
class UI{

constructor(){}

this.box = document.querySelector(".box");
this.footer = document.querySelector(".footer");

render(){
.......
}

}
```

Thus if we omit constructor then we won't be able to access variables box and footer in newly created instances of UI. Is that right?

Comment: Your above code will result in a `SyntaxError`, so it is not equivalent to the lower code, which doesn't

Comment: `class` properties must be a `method`. Your `both` snippet is incorrect. You cannot perform operations this way, need to use methods

Comment: Your `box` and `footer` can't be there where you have them. That's what you typically put into a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you omit the constructor, an implicit default constructor is used. The default constructor looks exactly like the one in your example.

For more thorough information look at the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor).

Answer (score 2):

Functionally, there's no difference. The `constructor` is optional.

So, if your constructor is *empty*, you can choose to leave it out:

[image]

Note how the left variant doesn't specify a constructor, but still has one. That's the default constructor, for when no constuctor has been specified:

```
constructor() {}
```

For derived classes, the default constructor is different:

```
constructor(...args) {
  super(...args);
}
```